# CLion Related Symbol opened in vertical tab

Tags: plugins, clion

Is it possible (probably with a help of plugin) to have the related symbol opened automatically when you have editors split vertically?

The Naviagate -> Related Symbol is doing it per request, but I'm wondering if it could always be done and the result shown in the split editor next to it. So no matter what cpp file I'm editing I would have the appropriate h file visible with it as well.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in quick info (Ctrl+Q)?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/viewing-inline-documentation.html

Comment: Is not exactly what I needed (to see unimplemented methods, or wiseversa, changed implementation and want to update definition). But the Ctrl+Q is pretty helpful as well, so thank you for your tip.